# How do I call my smart contract functions through web3 js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

So I am very new to Blockchain development so sorry in advance!

I have deployed a very basic Smart Contract to the Ropsten testnet. I am developing a front-end and from here, I want to withdraw ether/wei from the contract address(using a withdraw method), to the account calling the function(injected Metamask). It works perfect when I go onto etherscan to my contract and use the withdraw function there directly. I just don't know how to call the withdraw function through web3 js properly. I keep getting the following error message...

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/46rOt.jpg

Can someone help point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Bank{
    mapping(address=>uint) balances;

    function deposit() public payable{
        balances[msg.sender]+=msg.value;
    }
    function withdraw(uint amount) public{
        if(balances[msg.sender]>=amount){
            balances[msg.sender]-=amount;
            msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
Web3 = require('web3');

if (typeof web3 != 'undefined')
{
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    console.log("existing web3: provider " + typeof web3);
    console.log(web3.currentProvider);
}
else{
    //To Do..
    web3 = new Web3(new 
    Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/"));
    console.log("new provider " + web3);
}

console.log(web3.isConnected());
console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]);

abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMyBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]');

var bankContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
contractInstance = bankContract.at('myaddressishere');
console.log (contractInstance);

function withdraw() {
    contractInstance.withdraw(300000000000000000, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]);`? Are you seeing the address you expect?

Comment: It returns undefined. My actual smart contract address is returned however. The error is thrown when I execute the withdraw method/function.

Comment: This probably means MetaMask is locked or in privacy mode, assuming you're using the MetaMask path through the code. The error is because the `from` address is invalid (specifically, it's `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks for the help  smarx, really appreciate it as it's part of my final year project.  It does seem to have fixed it as the output of console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]); returns my address. However I now have run into another problem when I try the withdraw function.. https://imgur.com/a/DIJGZS2

Comment: As the error says, you need to pass a callback parameter. `contractInstance.withdraw(300000000000000000, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}, function (err,  result) { /* ... */ });`

Comment: Thank you soo much for the help! I owe you a beer :D